How do I make an animated svg work? .Net MAUI
I have an animated SVG that I want to implement in my application, I have found a way but I don't know if it is the most appropriate.
The thing is that it works for Android while it doesn't work on iOS.
This is the xaml.cs:
private void LoadSvg()
{
    string svgContent = @"
            <svg viewbox='0 0 64 48'>
                <style>
                    :is(#back2087, #front2087) {
                        fill: none;
                        stroke-width: 3;
                        stroke-linecap: round;
                        stroke-linejoin: round;
                    }
                    #back2087 {
                        fill: none;
                        stroke: currentColor;
                        opacity: 0.1;
                    }
                    #front2087 {
                        fill: none;
                        stroke: currentColor;
                        stroke-dasharray: 48, 144;
                        stroke-dashoffset: 192;
                        animation: dash_682 1.4s linear infinite;
                    }
                    @keyframes dash_682 {
                        72.5% {
                            opacity: 0;
                        }
                        to {
                            stroke-dashoffset: 0;
                        }
                    }
                </style>
                <polyline points='0.157 23.954, 14 23.954, 21.843 48, 43 0, 50 24, 64 24' id='back2087'/>
                <polyline points='0.157 23.954, 14 23.954, 21.843 48, 43 0, 50 24, 64 24' id='front2087'/>
            </svg>";

SvgWebView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource
{
    Html = svgContent
};

}
And in the view:
 <WebView x:Name="SvgWebView" HeightRequest="70" WidthRequest="70" BackgroundColor="Transparent" />


Does it has to be WebView? Something like lottie view is out of the question?

Use SMIL rather than CSS animation.

@H.A.H. idk what is lottie

@RobertLongson is a open source svg idk how to make one

@H.A.H. and lottie would work on iOS?

@Giorgio before we speak for lotties, can you quickly add xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" to the SVG to check if it will start working?

@H.A.H. but I have (http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui)

https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#SMIL_animations

@Giorgio in some browsers , if you have this: '' you will not see the svg. but if you have this:  svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg viewbox='0 0 64 48' it will magically start showing.

@H.A.H. I try Lottie and that works thx

@Giorgio yes, lottie is what I am running also. Good luck with your project.
